# laravel pdf package doesn't work and show blank pages with some text

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

Use PDF package. Show 150+ blank pages with some texts.
When I click pdf button.

**Controller page**

```
$data      = self::getOrderSheetReport($param);
$pdf       = \PDF::loadView('bPack.report.sales.orderSheet.report', $data);
$file_name = 'orderSheet-'.date('Y-m-d').'.pdf';
return $pdf->stream($file_name);
```

**Blade page**

```
 <a href="{{$pdf_url}}" class="btn btn-default" target="_blank">PDF</a>
```

Comment: What package you use for generating pdf?

Comment: I saw this name on composer.json . So I think our previous developer use this package.... niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf: "^4.0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same issue, I had included layouts.app.blade in view.
Removing that file solved my problem.